# How to download Muliple files (image/video url) by DownloadManager in Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Download Manager is the best way to download single file in android, It maintain Notification bar also.but how i can download Multiple files by it and show the whole downloading status by progressing bar in Notification.

Please suggest any library for it or any code snippet.

Comment: If I got you correctly, enqueuing two items at once will give you exactly what you want by default.

Comment: When i am enqueuing mutiple times, it shows mutiple file downloading in notification bar, i just want one notification progress bar for whole multiple files.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: `DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
   Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse("http://demo.mysamplecode.com/Sencha_Touch/CountryServlet?start=0&limit=999");
 DownloadManager.Request request = new 
 DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
 downloadManager.enqueue(request); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably hide the `DownloadManager`'s notification and show your own, that should do what you want.

To disable [`setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManger.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setNotificationVisibility(int)) to hide the notification.

To show download progress, you can register a `ContentObserver` on `DownloadManager`'s database to get periodic updates and update your own notification with it.

```
Cursor mDownloadManagerCursor = mDownloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query());
if (mDownloadManagerCursor != null) {
    mDownloadManagerCursor.registerContentObserver(mDownloadFileObserver);
}
```

And the `ContentObserver` will look something like:

```
private ContentObserver mDownloadFileObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Cursor cursor = mDownloadManager.query(new DownloadManager.Query());

        if (cursor != null) {
            long bytesDownloaded = 0;
            long totalBytes = 0;

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                bytesDownloaded += cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                totalBytes += cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
            }

            float progress = (float) (bytesDownloaded * 1.0 / totalBytes);
            showNotificationWithProgress(progress);

            cursor.close();
        }
    }
};
```

And the notification with progress can be shown with:

```
public void showNotificationWithProgress(Context context, int progress) {
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(0,
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Downloading...")
                    .setContentText("Progress")
                    .setProgress(100, progress * 100, false)
                    .setOnGoing(true)
                    .build());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for give me a great suggestion, Can you give me some code snippet of Content Observer on Download Manager to update notification bar, actually i am new on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day.